# When I select No the Display Alert message displays twice why? How do I get to display alert only once when i select NO?

Tags: xamarin

public async void clearswitchHandle_Toggled(object sender, 
    Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
        {

```
        var yesSelected = await DisplayAlert("WARNING!!!", "Are you sure you want to CLEAR DATA entered", "YES", "NO");
        if (yesSelected == true)
        {
            clearButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        else 
        {
            clearSwitch.IsToggled = false;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to lock this async method, it could be called more than once:

```
private bool lockAlert;
public async void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e) 
{
        if (lockAlert) return;
        lockAlert=true;

        var ok = await DisplayAlert("WARNING!!!", "Are you sure you want to CLEAR DATA entered", "YES", "NO");
        if (ok)
        {
            clearButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            clearSwitch.IsToggled = false;
        }

        lockAlert=false;
    }
```